# Why didn't Rem die immediately after being mutilated so severely?

Tags: re-zero

In episode 15 of Re:Zero Betelgeuse mutilated Rem which should have killed her. But that didn't happen. Instead, she survives and crawls to Subaru with her last strength, frees him of the chains and finally dies in his arms.

I mean, among other fatal wounds her neck/ cervical spine was torn apart. I'm not a biologist or physician, so correct me if I'm wrong, but aren't you dead if your neck is torn apart?

And according to someone who's read the LN, she had been mutilated by Betelgeuse even further i.a. he ripped her in two halves. There's definitely no human being who's able to survive this.
The only plausible reason I can think of is Rem's demon race. I'm not sure about it, though.

Comment: Iirc as a demon she has regenerative abilities

Comment: Also, if she was human....it wouldn't be the first time a ripped in half human has lived longer than they would in real life.  This is fiction after all.     Also....spoilers.....as I have yet to see this series.......and well.....thanks -_-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In response to your 'biological knowledge' - In any instance, if a human was to have their neck twisted the same way Rem had hers, they would 100% die, so you're correct in your thoughts there.

The best way to consider this is to think of it as 'Anime/Manga/Novel Logic' and accept it, though I know that's not an acceptable answer, so I'll attempt to give reason to her survival.

The idea that she was torn in half should be forgotten when talking about the anime, as that wasn't the case, though as for how she survived in the novel is beyond me and I don't want to attempt to guess at how she survived.

As for how she survived in the anime, that would come down to a few things.

- **Life force**. If she were to have a large amount of life force, which I assume she does, as she is a demon (it's known in multiple novels and such that demons have a much larger life force than that of humans), it's safe to assume she also has this trait.
- **Willpower**. This one is a bit iffy and is more of a placeholder to further the point, though may not have any relevance. If someone has the will to carry on living, especially with the amount of willpower she shows (she states that the cultists took her "*reason to die*" when they took Subaru, meaning she was willing to die for him), it's not too far a stretch to say she would use any and all abilities to stay alive in order to free him, which she does. It's plausible that she was using magic to keep herself alive, though that's speculation, without proof.
- **Biology**. We can't say for sure that she has the same anatomy as humans and that she would react the same to the treatment as we would, so we can't rule her dead after the treatment, even if we do see it as logical. We could say that the body contortions that were applied were simply hindering her ability to move and her death came from the damage she sustained on her journey to where Subaru was being held. (We know she had lost a lot of blood, as we witnessed her get a knife lodged in her left shoulder earlier, as well as her arm burned.) Thinking that she would make it to Betelguese and his hideout without receiving further injury is an insult to writing, so we'll assume she took damage (as well as the blood dripping down her head, as well as tattered clothes, it's safe to assume her journey was rough). All that damage could have been the underlying factor in her death.

We can't really say for sure why she survived as we don't know 100% how her anatomy works, how much of a play on her life the willpower and life force come into it, as well as a few unconsidered factors that I forgot to mention.

Comment: The "fiction" logic is always the answer, even if the injury is not life threatening, but severe such as the limb chopped off, the body immediately goes into a state of shock. So they wouldn't be able to do anything, much less have an emotional farewell.

Answer (score 0):

Rem and Ram are demons.Rem still has her horn so shes still strong and can endure that long with those broken bones until her very last breath but that aint same to Ram since she lost her horn when they were young.